# Automatically Slicing Large TIFF File with Photoshop and Save Slices into TIFF Files?

Tags: save, slice, photoshop, tiff, web-slice

I have a TIFF file. I want to slice it **automatically** (specifying the number of slices in horizontal and vertical) and save them into TIFF files (I don't want to change the format to png or ...)

I know that in photoshop you can choose the slice tool>>right click>>Divide Slice>>Save for web

**However, the "Save for web" doesn't offer saving in TIFF Format and also I don't think it can work for large file (which is the case here).**

Anything that can help (script, plugin) is welcome

Comment: You can convert a slice into layers (and then save as tiff) [see SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/425811/is-it-possible-in-photoshop-to-convert-slices-into-photoshop-layers)

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest Thanks I will try it.

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest Please see the answer below. I depended on direct way of saving into Tiff files instead of that way.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of some online codes, I created the script below which is capable of automatically slicing a big TIFF into smaller Tiff files:

```
#target photoshop
function main(){
if(!documents.length) return;
var dlg=
"dialog{text:'Script Interface',bounds:[100,100,380,290],"+
"panel0:Panel{bounds:[10,10,270,180] , text:'' ,properties:{borderStyle:'etched',su1PanelCoordinates:true},"+
"title:StaticText{bounds:[60,10,220,40] , text:'File Chop' ,properties:{scrolling:undefined,multiline:undefined}},"+
"panel1:Panel{bounds:[10,40,250,130] , text:'' ,properties:{borderStyle:'etched',su1PanelCoordinates:true},"+
"statictext1:StaticText{bounds:[10,10,111,30] , text:'Accross' ,properties:{scrolling:undefined,multiline:undefined}},"+
"statictext2:StaticText{bounds:[140,10,230,27] , text:'Down' ,properties:{scrolling:undefined,multiline:undefined}},"+
"across:DropDownList{bounds:[10,30,100,50]},"+
"down:DropDownList{bounds:[140,30,230,50]},"+
"saveFiles:Checkbox{bounds:[10,60,230,80] , text:'Save and Close new files?'}},"+
"button0:Button{bounds:[10,140,110,160] , text:'Ok' },"+
"button1:Button{bounds:[150,140,250,160] , text:'Cancel' }}};"
var win = new Window(dlg,'File Chop');
if(version.substr(0,version.indexOf('.'))>9){
win.panel0.title.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont("Georgia","BOLD",20);
g = win.graphics;
var myBrush = g.newBrush(g.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1]);
g.backgroundColor = myBrush;
var myPen =g.newPen (g.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1],lineWidth=1);
}
win.center();
  for(var i=1;i<31;i++){
   win.panel0.panel1.across.add ('item', i);     
   win.panel0.panel1.down.add ('item', i);     
  }
win.panel0.panel1.across.selection=0;
win.panel0.panel1.down.selection=0;
var done = false; 
    while (!done) { 
      var x = win.show(); 
      if (x == 0 || x == 2) {
        win.canceled = true;
        done = true; 
      } else if (x == 1) { 
        done = true; 
        {
if(!documents.length)return;
var startRulerUnits = preferences.rulerUnits;
preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
doc = app.activeDocument;
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;
doc.flatten();
var tilesAcross = parseInt(win.panel0.panel1.across.selection.index)+1;
var tilesDown =parseInt(win.panel0.panel1.down.selection.index)+1;
var tileWidth = parseInt(doc.width/tilesAcross);
var tileHeight = parseInt(doc.height/tilesDown);
var SaveFiles = win.panel0.panel1.saveFiles.value;
ProcessFiles(tilesDown,tilesAcross,tileWidth,tileHeight,SaveFiles);
app.preferences.rulerUnits = startRulerUnits;      
      } 
   }
  }
}
main();
function ProcessFiles(Down,Across,offsetX,offsetY,SaveFiles){
 try{
var newName = activeDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
}catch(e){var newName="UntitledChop"}
var Path='';
try{
Path =  activeDocument.path;
}catch(e){Path = "~/Desktop";}
 if(SaveFiles){
Path = Folder(decodeURI(Path) +"/FileChop");
if(!Path.exists) Path.create();
     }
TLX = 0; TLY = 0; TRX = offsetX; TRY = 0;
BRX = offsetX; BRY = offsetY; BLX = 0; BLY = offsetY;
 for(var a = 0; a < Down; a++){
  for(var i = 0;i <Across; i++){
            var NewFileName = newName +"#"+a+"-"+i;
   app.activeDocument.duplicate (NewFileName, true);
    activeDocument.selection.select([[TLX,TLY],[TRX,TRY],[BRX,BRY],[BLX,BLY]], SelectionType.REPLACE, 0, false); 
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID( "Crop" ), undefined, DialogModes.NO );
    app.activeDocument.selection.deselect();
 if(SaveFiles){
var saveFile = File(decodeURI(Path+"/"+NewFileName+".tiff"));
SaveTIFF(saveFile);
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
}
    activeDocument = documents[0];
TLX = offsetX * (i+1) ; TRX  = TLX + offsetX; BRX = TRX; BLX = TLX;  
    }
TLX = 0; TLY = offsetY * (a +1); TRX = offsetX; TRY = offsetY * (a +1);
BRX = offsetX; BRY = TRY + offsetY; BLX = 0; BLY = (offsetY * (a +1)+offsetY);

 }
 if(SaveFiles){
Path.execute()
    }
}
function SaveTIFF(saveFile){
tiffSaveOptions = new TiffSaveOptions();   
tiffSaveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;   
tiffSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true;   
tiffSaveOptions.layers = true;  
tiffSaveOptions.imageCompression = TIFFEncoding.NONE;  
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, tiffSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);   
}
```